# condtionally render the content in vf pag email template in salesforce

Tags: salesforce, visualforce, salesforce-lightning

Depending upon account type( personal, commercial) need to render welcome message in VF page with if condition.

relatedToType="Account"

for commercial account

{!relatedTo.Name},

```
    
for personal account
```

Dear {!relatedTo.FirstName},

```
how to render the given requirement with if condition in vf page.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

`Dear {!IF(relatedTo.isPersonAccount, relatedTo.FirstName, relatedTo.Name)}` for simple things. If you have bigger blocks of text - most VF tags have `rendered` attribute to turn them on and off.

That's a weird requirement though. "Dear Four Seasons Total Landscaping..." ;)

Who do you send it to when it's a company? Maybe use `recipientType="Contact"` and then `recipient.FirstName`?

Comment: this works fine.but the requirement is "dear" should be present for personal account only and for commercial accounts only name should be ther without "dear".Thanks

Comment: `{!IF(relatedTo.isPersonAccount, 'Dear ' + relatedTo.FirstName, relatedTo.Name)}`?

Comment: this does work. Thanks for the help, this was much needed.Thank you!!

Comment: can we add the same requrement to                                             
             relatedToType="Case"


<messaging:htmlEmailBody >
<html>
<body>
    <p>
       {!IF(relatedTo.isPersonAccount, 'Dear ' + relatedTo.FirstName, relatedTo.Name)},<br/><br/>                                                                                                                        when i try  add this i am getting : Invalid field isPersonAccount for SObject Case. is there a way around?Thanks

Comment: `IF(relatedTo.Account.isPersonAccount, 'Dear ' + relatedTo.Account.FirstName, relatedTo.Account.Name)` ?